# How to get contents of a PUT request?

Tags: php, rest

If a client sent a PUT request with an array for example:

```
$a = array('age' => 18);
$rest->put('/api/users/9', $a);
```

How does your rest API get the $a array?

Comment: [`file_get_contents('php://input');`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: @zzzzBov That works. Make that answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the request body at [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), but be warned that it's volatile and can only be read once*.

```
file_get_contents('php://input');‌​
```

You'll then need to parse this as a URL to use it as an array.

<sub>* details are on the linked page</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the body of the request.

Comment: How do you get the body of the request? Do you mean `$_REQUEST` it doesn't work.